# Changing the shape of chart generated by apache poi for excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I have a java file generating an excel sheet containing a ton of data. For better user experience, we decided to simply generate a line chart out of the data.

Generating the chart wasn't difficult, but getting it to be the exact shape as we need it is a problem. Currently, the chart border looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the border is curved at the corner. I want it to look like this:

[image]

So, far I have not been able to find a way to do that. The documentation isn't very detailed about this.

Answer (score 2):

So in your opinion rounded corners are outdated? I am this opinion too, but as it seems `Microsoft` is not. Because if in `CTChartSpace` the `RoundedCorners` is not set, then it is `true`by default.

But fortunately we can set it as needed using following method:

```
private static void setRoundedCorners(XSSFChart chart, boolean setVal) {
    if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewRoundedCorners();
    chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners().setVal(setVal);
}
```

Using the current Apache POI versions, which are using `XDDF` for charts, this also can be:

```
private static void setRoundedCorners(XDDFChart chart, boolean setVal) {
    if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewRoundedCorners();
    chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners().setVal(setVal);
}
```

Complete Example:

Get any chart example from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/ and then call

```
setRoundedCorners(chart, false);
```

after chart creating.