# Remove border area in apache poi bar chart in excel

Tags: apache-poi, bar-chart

I created bar chart in excel file using apache poi. How can I remove border/margin outside the plotarea? The blue border area in the following image.[image]

I added the blue part by editing the created excel file. Before the edit, it was white. Here is the function code that creates this graph:

```
    public void createBarChart(double[] values, boolean[] passed, String[] labels,
                           int Dx1, int Dy1, int Dx2, int Dy2,
                           int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2){
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(Dx1, Dy1, Dx2, Dy2, col1, row1, col2, row2);
    Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);


    CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();

    CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
    CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
    //CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
    //ctBoolean.setVal(false);
    ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL);

    // Add the bars
    int length = values.length;
    for (int s = 0; s < length; s++) {
        CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
        CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
        ctSerTx.setV(labels[s]);
        ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(s);

        CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
        CTNumData ctNumData = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumLit();
        ctNumData.addNewPtCount().setVal(1);
        CTNumVal ctNumVal = ctNumData.addNewPt();
        ctNumVal.setIdx(0);
        ctNumVal.setV("" + values[s]);


        //at least the border lines in Libreoffice Calc ;-)
        CTShapeProperties ctShapeProperties = ctBarSer.addNewSpPr();
        if(passed[s]) {
            // bar color, green: passed
            ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0, (byte)128, 0});
        }
        else {
            // bar color, red: failed
            ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte) 255, 0, 0});
        }
        //ctShapeProperties.addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{0, 0, 0}); // black
        ctShapeProperties.addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255}); // white
    }


    //telling the BarChart that it has axes and giving them Ids

    ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
    ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);


    //cat axis
    CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
    ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
    CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
    ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(true);
    ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
    ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
    ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

    //val axis
    CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx();
    ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
    ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
    ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(true);
    ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
    ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
    ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

    // Remove rounded corner
    if (((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners() == null){
        ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().addNewRoundedCorners();
    }

    ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners().setVal(false);
    //chart area (chartspace) without border line
    ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();


}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, I suspect you are creating a `XSSFChart`.

How have you set this thick blue border? Normally there is a thin blue border having rounded corners by default. How get rid of the rounded corners is answered already: [Changing the shape of chart generated by apache poi for excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255527/changing-the-shape-of-chart-generated-by-apache-poi-for-excel-sheet/44265659#44265659).

But if you wants to format the border, then you need to know that the [CTChartSpace](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTChartSpace.java) has [CTShapeProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTShapeProperties.java#CTShapeProperties).

So:

```
...
        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 20);

        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

//chart area (chartspace) without border line
((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();
...
```

Maybe the border around the plot area and the gap between plot area and chart area shall be removed, then:

```
...
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
ctPlotArea.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();
org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTManualLayout ctManualLayout = ctPlotArea.getLayout().addNewManualLayout();
ctManualLayout.addNewX().setVal(0);
ctManualLayout.addNewY().setVal(0);
ctManualLayout.addNewW().setVal(1);
ctManualLayout.addNewH().setVal(1);
...
```

Comment: Yes, I first created XSSFChart. I set the blue border from Excel file itself (just by changing the color, by default, it is white). I can now change the round shape with your suggestion. But I could not get rid of the blue area with your code. I have to display my barChart in small area (like 2 cells by 2 cells). So, I need to get rid of the blue area to make the graph larger. Otherwise, most of the space is occupied by that blue portion.

Comment: @Masum: "But I could not get rid of the blue area with your code.": Then I cannot help further until you are providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For me the `((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();` works with `chart`being a new created `XSSFChart`.  Maybe it must be `((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().unsetLn();` first and then `((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill());` for you. But this is a wild guess only.

Comment: @Masum: Maybe the border around the plot area and the gap between plot area and chart area shall be removed? See my supplements.

Comment: Yes, please. Where is your supplements?