# Create a Excel LineChart with apache poi java

Tags: java, excel, apache

I've been trying to create a method that will create a linechart (data is exported from a database and a I have method to select cellrange). I'm using poi-3.17.jar (according to their website it's the latest stable version https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.17).

There are some forums both here and on the apache poi website that provides some examples, however I've not yet been successful in creating a working method.

Does anyone have a working example of creating a linechart (not scatterchart)?
Information regarding imports would also be very helpful.

BR

Comment: Have you already tried code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255527/changing-the-shape-of-chart-generated-by-apache-poi-for-excel-sheet/44265659#44265659?

Comment: Yes, this code is very similar to this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138/apache-poi-excel-line-chart-points. I get the following error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.ChartDataFactory.createLineChartData()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/charts/LineChartData;" this line gives me the error: LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

Comment: The code in my linked answer works correct using `apache poi` version `3.17`. I can reproduce your run time error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` when I compile the code using `apache poi` version `3.17` classes in class path but run the code then using lower version classes in class path while run time. Don't do this!

Comment: could you upload your code and list the jars you use? These are the Jar files that I use (also some JDBC that is not important in this case): dom4j-1.6.1 poi-3.17 poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203 poi-ooxml-3.11 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203

Comment: The code in my linked answer is complete. But you are using `apache poi` jars from different versions (poi-3.17 poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203 poi-ooxml-3.11 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203) **[Don't do this!](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204)**. Do using only version 3.17 jars from `apache poi` instead.

Comment: Finally I managed to update all Jars to compatible versions, thank you for your help. Could you make a your comments to an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer? Merry Xmas and a happy new year :)