# Apache POI - Set two Charts side by side on word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Is there any way to set two charts side by side on the word document using Apache poi? I have created two charts which are coming one after another onto the word document.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;


public class daf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a new Word document
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        

        // Create a severitychart
        XWPFChart severityChart = doc.createChart(10 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 5 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

        // Create chart data source
        String[] categories = new String[]{"Critical", "High", "Medium","Low","Best Practice"};
        Double[] values = new Double[]{(double) 1,(double) 2,(double) 3,(double) 4,(double) 5};
        XDDFDataSource<String> categoryDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories);
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valueDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);

        // Create chart data
        XDDFPieChartData data = (XDDFPieChartData) severityChart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
        
        severityChart.setTitleText("# of Vulnerabilites by Severity");
        severityChart.setTitleOverlay(false);
                
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoryDataSource, valueDataSource);
      

        // Plot the chart
        severityChart.plot(data);
        severityChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);;
        severityChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
        severityChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().setSeparator(" - ");
        
        
         // Create a categorychart
            XWPFChart categoryChart = doc.createChart(10 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 5 * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

            // Create chart data source
            String[] categories1 = new String[]{"Critical", "High", "Medium","Low","Best Practice"};
            Double[] values1 = new Double[]{(double) 1,(double) 2,(double) 3,(double) 4,(double) 5};
            XDDFDataSource<String> categoryDataSource1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories1);
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valueDataSource1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values1);
                    
         // Create the category axis
         XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = categoryChart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
         XDDFValueAxis valueAxis = categoryChart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
         
         XDDFChartData data1 = categoryChart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR,  categoryAxis, valueAxis);
         
           
            XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data1.addSeries(categoryDataSource1, valueDataSource1);
            series1.setTitle(null); //Title should be mandatory.
            // Plot the chart
            categoryChart.plot(data1);
            
        // Save the document
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("chart_document.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
        doc.close();

        System.out.println("chart created successfully!");
    }
}
```

This code creates a pie chart and bar chart one after another. Can we modify the above code so that we can make the charts side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Microsoft Word document in Office Open XML format (`*.docx`), charts are embedded in the documents body. Same as pictures or other shapes too, they either are in anchored drawings or are inline with text. So far, Apache POI only supports charts inline with text. Those are in text runs (`XWPFRun`). So they are placed where the text run is placed in the document.

Using current Apache POI version `5.2.3`
there are three `XWPFDocument.createChart` methods to create `XWPFChart`. See [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html).

The first one, without parameters, creates a chart in a new text run in a new paragraph, having default size. The second one has parameters `width` and `height` and creates a chart in a new text run in a new paragraph, having the size given. The third one has parameters `run`, `width` and `height` and creates a chart in the text run given, having the size given. So using the third one, one has full control where the chart shall be placed in the text.

Following complete example creates two charts in one paragraph in different text runs in that paragraph. So, as long not automated line breaks occur, the charts will be placed side by side.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordCharts {
    
 private static void createBarChart(XWPFRun run, String[] categories, Double[] values, PresetColor color, 
  BarDirection direction, String chartTitleText, String seriesTitle, 
  int width, int height) throws Exception {
      
  // Create the chart
  XWPFDocument  document = run.getParent().getDocument();
  XWPFChart chart = document.createChart(run, width * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, height * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);
  
  // Create chart data sources
  XDDFDataSource<String> categoryDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories);
  XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valueDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);
         
  // Create the category axis
  XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
  
  // Create the value axis
  XDDFValueAxis valueAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
  
  // Set how the axis cross - for example at zero point of value axis
  valueAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  
  // Set AxisCrossBetween, so the value axis crosses the category axis between the categories.
  // Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.
  valueAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

  // Create chart data
  XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, categoryAxis, valueAxis);
  
  // Set bar direction
  ((XDDFBarChartData)data).setBarDirection(direction);   
  
  // Set chart title - optinal
  if (chartTitleText != null && !chartTitleText.isBlank())
   chart.setTitleText(chartTitleText);
  
  // Add series
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoryDataSource, valueDataSource);
  
  // Set series title - not optional 
  if (seriesTitle == null || seriesTitle.isBlank()) seriesTitle = "Series1";
  series.setTitle(seriesTitle, null);

  // Set series fill color - necessary for LibreOffice as this will not use default colors
  solidFillSeries(series, color);

  // Plot the chart
  chart.plot(data);
     
 }

 private static void createPieChart(XWPFRun run, String[] categories, Double[] values, byte[][] colors, 
  String chartTitleText, String seriesTitle, 
  int width, int height) throws Exception {
      
  // Create the chart
  XWPFDocument  document = run.getParent().getDocument();
  XWPFChart chart = document.createChart(run, width * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, height * Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);
  
  // Create chart data sources
  XDDFDataSource<String> categoryDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories);
  XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valueDataSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);
         
  // Create chart data
  XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
  
  // Set chart title - optinal
  if (chartTitleText != null && !chartTitleText.isBlank())
   chart.setTitleText(chartTitleText);
  
  // Add series
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categoryDataSource, valueDataSource);
  
  // Set series title - not optional 
  if (seriesTitle == null || seriesTitle.isBlank()) seriesTitle = "Series1";
  series.setTitle(seriesTitle, null);
  
  // data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in LibreOffice
  int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
  for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
    .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(colors[p]);
  }

  // Plot the chart
  chart.plot(data);
     
 }

 private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData.Series series, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setFillProperties(fill);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // Create some normal XWPF content 
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Chart Examples");

  // Create paragraph for the charts
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // Create run for text
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Chart1: ");

  // Create a run to place the first chart
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  String[] categories = new String[]{"Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"};
  Double[] values = new Double[]{3d, 5d, 2d, 4d, 1d};
  createBarChart(run, categories, values, PresetColor.BLUE, BarDirection.COL, "Bar Chart", "Series1", 5, 5);
  
  // Create run for text
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" Chart2: ");
  
  // Create a run to place the second chart
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  categories = new String[]{"Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4"};
  values = new Double[]{1d, 4d, 3d, 2d};
  byte[][] colors = new byte[][]{
   new byte[]{(byte)255,0,0}, 
   new byte[]{0, (byte)255,0}, 
   new byte[]{0,0,(byte)255}, 
   new byte[]{(byte)255, (byte)255, 0}, 
  };
  createPieChart(run, categories, values, colors, "Pie Chart", null, 5, 5);

  // Create paragraph below the charts
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    
  // Save the document
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WorddocumentWithCharts.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
 
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Axel Richter. Thanks for commenting. I have created a pie chart and bar chart with apache poi and those charts were coming one after another. Edited the question and added the code. Would you please guide me how to set pie chart and bar chart side by side? Thanks again for comment.

Comment: @Bharath Naidu Yenumula: The answer stays the same. I have updated my example. Now it creates a bar chart and a pie chart.

Comment: The way you have provided the details instead of only providing the solution is commendable. Exactly what i was looking for. Solved my doubt and thank you.

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter just out of curiosity, is there any way to create chart area shape to rectangle instead of above shape. Thank you so much.

Comment: Solved it from your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255527/changing-the-shape-of-chart-generated-by-apache-poi-for-excel-sheet. Thank you for providing the details. It was very helpful.